# what am I missing here? DataGrid and ListView not getting populated in WPF application

Tags: c#, listview, datagrid, connection-string, sql-server-2012

I'm following a book on C# object oriented programming and this application isn't working. The DataGrid and ListView aren't populating.
What important point am I missing?

Only thing I can think of is that I'm not connecting to the database because I don't know the syntax for the connection string, what to put in data source= and so on. The data source is .\sqlexpress in the book, but mine is sql server 2012. There is no error, so I don't know what to do.
Here is the code as it is in the book:

```
return @"Integrated Security=True;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" +
"Initial Catalog=OfficeSupply";
```

Here is the code as I wrote it:

```
    return @"Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=OfficeSupply" +
            @"User ID=username;Password=password";
```

I'm a total noob, so I'm not totally sure if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the issue:

```
return @"Integrated Security=True;Data Source=(local);" +
                     "Initial Catalog=OfficeSupply";
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look in the book at passing the listview a **SQL data source** or **Object Data Source** what your returning is the DB connection string which you really want in your app.Config XML file

Comment: Thank you so much... I found the solution in the books while checking out SQL data source.